# How to use Task type object in order to store data in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm studying Swift by making ToDo app.

I tried to store the data by using Task type object, 
but I got an error `Use of unresolved identifier 'Task'`

Could you give some advice please?

```
import UIKit

class AddTaskViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var taskTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    //// When Done Button Tapped
    @IBAction func doneButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let taskName = taskTextField.text

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        **let task = Task(context: context)**

        task.name = taskName
        task.category = taskCategory

        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: `Task` is supposed to be an `NSManagedObject` subclass. The creation depends on the settings in the Core Data model file.

Comment: Don’t forget to `import CoreData`

Comment: @vadian Could you explain more detail?

Comment: @Magnas I imported CoreData, but I still have an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set entity(name & category) in xcdatamodel.